# Jquery dynamically assign same function with different parameters to

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

Guys is it possible to assign Double click event to A HREF which is dynamically generated , to which i need to assign a user function with parameter that will differ for each a HREF.kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use *class* instead of *id* and do what Matt said.

```
$('.Class').live('click',function(event)
{
  myFunc($(this));
});
```

Comment: @Suresh, just class. add a 'class="something"' inside the a "father" tag. Then, on Jquery, you select the 'a' tags doing.. $(".class a"). It's a way to do that. Or just put a class on 'a' tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.generated').live('click',function(event)
{
  //determine params here

  myFunc(params);
});
```

For every 'a' tag that ends up on your page, when it is clicked, it will call myFunc with the jQuery version of itself as the paramater

Comment: each A href has an id , i do not want to assign the function for all  link ,only to dynamically generated ones , and  function parameters changes for each links.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function. This is a simple JavaScript. Using this method we can assign a function dynamically on an html element.

> var funcRef = new Function("testFunction()");
>   document.getElementById("elementid").onclick=funcRef;